String Number type date comparison with the number data type in Prisma
My totalGgr field in MongoDB stores integer values as strings, and I want to compare these string values with integers in Prisma within a Next.js application. How can I do that?

Below is the part of my query.
  if (params.totalGgrType === 'Greater than') {
    parentWhereCondition.totalGgr = {
      gt: totalGgrValue
    };
  } else {
    parentWhereCondition.totalGgr = {
      lt: totalGgrValue
    };
  }

I want to compare the number with the string data type in mongoDB using prisma query.
